# How to upload project to new repo on Github - old files have been deleted

Tags: git, github

I'm trying upload project to Github. Followed the instructions to set up repo, set-url and origin but...

```
git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 1860, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1860/1860), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1613/1613), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1860/1860), 464.30 MiB | 12.21 MiB/s, done.
Total 1860 (delta 449), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

At this point, it terminal hangs for a bit.

Then I receive this error:

```
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: "Big file 1"
This exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/user/MyStuff.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/MyStuff.git'
```

What baffles me is that the big file was deleted days ago and doesn't appear in terminal yet git seems to think it still exists.

What can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to remove the file from previous commits as well since those will also be pushed to Github. The BFG Repo-Cleaner can be used to do that.

More detailed instructions here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository